# Bash command to check if multiple files exist in the directory

Tags: bash, shell

Wanted to check if there are multiple files with the same prefix exist in that directory.

here directory --> `WORK_DIR` and file prefix -->`SRC_FILE_EXT`

i currently have the script like this:

```
if [ -s ${WORK_DIR}${SRC_FILE_EXT} ] ;  then
   echo "+ File is present on the source directory" >> $LOG_FILE
else

   echo "No files to move" >> $LOG_FILE
   exit 4
fi
```

But this script throws No files to move..

Could someone help me out here

Comment: (1) Your code does not check if file exists, but if file is not empty, use `-f` if you want to check for regular file exists. (2) The word "multiple" confuses me, as this is not part of your script. (3) Always quote paths/filenames!! Use `"${WORK_DIR}${SRC_FILE_EXT}"` and `"$LOG_FILE"`. (4) For debugging, make sure that `WORK_DIR` and `SRC_FILE_EXT` are correctly set when running `if`. And that you have a `/` in between. (5) For more debugging, use `set -x` to print out what is actually executed.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
shopt -s nullglob

set -- "$WORK_DIR/$SRC_FILE_EXT"*

printf 'There are %d names that match "%s"\n' "$#" "$WORK_DIR/$SRC_FILE_EXT*"
```

That is, expand the pattern that matches the names that you are interested in, setting the positional parameters.  The special variable `$#` will contain the number of matched names.   Set the `nullglob` shell option in `bash` to let the pattern expand to nothing if it does not match at all.

If you want to make sure that you don't match directories, you may use a simple loop that counts the non-directories:

```bash
shopt -s nullglob

num=0
for name in "$WORK_DIR/$SRC_FILE_EXT"*; do
    [ ! -d "$name" ] && num=$(( num + 1 ))
done

printf 'There are %d non-directories with names that match "%s"\n' "$num" "$WORK_DIR/$SRC_FILE_EXT*"
```

Using `find`:

```
find "$WORK_DIR" -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -name "$SRC_FILE_EXT*" -exec echo x \; | wc -l
```

(assuming your `find` knows about the non-standard `-maxdepth` predicate).  This would return the number of non-directories in `$WORK_DIR` whose names start with `$SRC_FILE_EXT`.

```
num=$( find "$WORK_DIR" -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -name "$SRC_FILE_EXT*" -exec echo x \; | wc -l )

printf 'There are %d non-directories with names that match "%s" in "%s"\n' \
    "$num" "$SRC_FILE_EXT*" "$WORK_DIR"
```

There is a subtle difference between using shell globs to match names and using `find` in that `find` is more strict with its file type matching.  The `find` utility will not detect a symbolic link to a file or a directory as a file or directory, but as a symbolic link, while the shell will dereference the symbolic link and test the thing that it links to.

Answer (score 0):

As you are talking of "files" in plural and a prefix, I suppose that the filenames contain `$SRC_FILE_EXT` with something after it, so you'd need a globbing pattern like `$SRC_FILE_EXT*`.

But this could give you multiple matches, while `test -s` takes only one argument.

So I suggest to modify your test to

```
if [ "$(find . -name \"${WORK_DIR}/${SRC_FILE_EXT}*\" )" != "" ]; then
```

Comment: Escaping the double quotes in the argument to `-name` would make `find` look for files with literal double quotes in their names. Also, the `-name` predicate will never be true for a pattern that contains a `/`.  You may test for a non-empty string with the `-n` test.